# Why doesn't my BufferedReader that reads while readLine!=null work?

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader, readline, reader

I have **file** called `"a.txt"` inside of which I have this data:

```
A
B
C
D
```

When I run this code, I get unexpected result:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("a.txt"));
while (true) {
    System.out.println ("start");
    while (bufferedReader.readLine () != null) {
        System.out.println (bufferedReader.readLine ());
    }
    Thread.sleep (1000);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
start
B
D
start
start
start
//keeps printing start
```

What I expected was of course:

```
start
A
B
C
D
start
start
//keeps printing start
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem? This honestly shocked me, as it looked easy when I first saw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each (successful) iteration of the loop, you're reading two lines - one in the while condition, and then another one in the loop's body. The line read in the loop's condition is discarded, and thus you see the missing line.

Instead, you can store the line in a variable in the loop's condition, and then use it in the loop's body:

```
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

bufferedReader.readLine () reads the next line and you're calling it twice

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `bufferedReader.readLine ()` twice whereas you are supposed to call it once. Do it as follows:

```
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
}
```